# Banned blocked IP location in Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: iptables, unlock, portscan

I am using this script for block port port scanning. If an IP is trying to using nmap or some scanner tool for port scanning IP, its IP will be move to blacklist for 86400 seconds. The tutorial I found [here (the link sometimes die)](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/06/15/how-to-protect-from-port-scanning-and-smurf-attack-in-linux-server-by-iptables/)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
# Script is for stoping Portscan and smurf attack

### first flush all the iptables Rules
iptables -F

# Protecting portscans
# Attacking IP will be locked for 24 hours (3600 x 24 = 86400 Seconds)
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP

# Remove attacking IP after 24 hours
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --remove
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --remove

# These rules add scanners to the portscan list, and log the attempt.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --name portscan --set -j LOG --log-prefix "portscan:"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --name portscan --set -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --name portscan --set -j LOG --log-prefix "portscan:"
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --name portscan --set -j DROP
```

The blocking is worked. But when I want to unblock an IP from blacklist, I cannot find where it is stored.
Tried with this:

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n
```

It give me no result. Maybe because I don't use an manual iptable command for blocking that IP.

When I use iptable-save command, the file content is:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Aug  1 09:55:24 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2573:464414]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2561:450932]
-A INPUT -m recent --rcheck --seconds 86400 --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -m recent --remove --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --set --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "portscan:"
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --set --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m recent --rcheck --seconds 86400 --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m recent --remove --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --set --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "portscan:"
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -m recent --set --name portscan --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug  1 09:55:24 2017
```

There is no sign of the blocked IP.
So how can I unblock an IP which blocked by above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various tables used with the recent module in iptables are stored at `/proc/net/xt_recent`. Example:

```
$ ls -l /proc/net/xt_recent
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 17:31 BADGUY_EMAIL
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 17:31 BADGUY_SSH
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 17:31 HTTP_01
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 17:31 HTTP_02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 17:31 HTTP_BAN
```

Now, say that we had a look at the `HTTP_BAN` table:

```
src=151.80.153.116 ttl: 54 last_seen: 4328384635 oldest_pkt: 1 4328384635, ..., 4328384635
src=96.49.73.155 ttl: 123 last_seen: 5452194021 oldest_pkt: 3 5452194014, ..., 5452194014
src=107.172.148.195 ttl: 55 last_seen: 5129807106 oldest_pkt: 15 5129803346, ..., 5129803346
src=125.64.94.206 ttl: 50 last_seen: 4540016391 oldest_pkt: 11 4540008881, ..., 4540016391
src=173.180.45.3 ttl: 63 last_seen: 5037092972 oldest_pkt: 15 5037078444, ..., 5037078444
src=77.66.1.97 ttl: 46 last_seen: 4981357498 oldest_pkt: 17 4981346351, ..., 4981346351
src=78.73.133.234 ttl: 55 last_seen: 5009073697 oldest_pkt: 9 5009058041, ..., 5009058041
src=23.16.13.188 ttl: 125 last_seen: 4353548286 oldest_pkt: 1 4353548286, ..., 4353548286
src=131.247.152.158 ttl: 46 last_seen: 5187361776 oldest_pkt: 23 5187345808, ..., 5187345808
src=173.196.177.69 ttl: 51 last_seen: 4741647347 oldest_pkt: 21 4741643594, ..., 4741643594
src=122.114.223.46 ttl: 49 last_seen: 4914484055 oldest_pkt: 9 4914477305, ..., 4914477305
```

And decided that we wanted to allow two addresses that are currently in the list:

```
$ echo -122.114.223.46 | sudo tee /proc/net/xt_recent/HTTP_BAN
-122.114.223.46
$ echo -173.180.45.3 | sudo tee /proc/net/xt_recent/HTTP_BAN
-173.180.45.3
```

And now check the list again:

```
src=151.80.153.116 ttl: 54 last_seen: 4328384635 oldest_pkt: 1 4328384635, ..., 4328384635
src=96.49.73.155 ttl: 123 last_seen: 5452194021 oldest_pkt: 3 5452194014, ..., 5452194014
src=107.172.148.195 ttl: 55 last_seen: 5129807106 oldest_pkt: 15 5129803346, ..., 5129803346
src=125.64.94.206 ttl: 50 last_seen: 4540016391 oldest_pkt: 11 4540008881, ..., 4540016391
src=77.66.1.97 ttl: 46 last_seen: 4981357498 oldest_pkt: 17 4981346351, ..., 4981346351
src=78.73.133.234 ttl: 55 last_seen: 5009073697 oldest_pkt: 9 5009058041, ..., 5009058041
src=23.16.13.188 ttl: 125 last_seen: 4353548286 oldest_pkt: 1 4353548286, ..., 4353548286
src=131.247.152.158 ttl: 46 last_seen: 5187361776 oldest_pkt: 23 5187345808, ..., 5187345808
src=173.196.177.69 ttl: 51 last_seen: 4741647347 oldest_pkt: 21 4741643594, ..., 4741643594
```

And observe that those two ip addresses are gone.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, iptables version v1.4.21, there is no "/proc/net/xt_recent" directory. I tried to search for "xt_recent" but didn't found.

Comment: The directory won't be there if there isn't anything in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to make an IP "banned", then the directory appeared, inside the directory, there is a fire named "portscan" which contain banned IPs.  It's  exact what I want.